# CORS error encountered when writing to google documents from website form

Tags: ajax, angularjs, google-sheets, cors, google-docs

I have a form in my website that should write a text field "email" to a google spreadsheet.
When the form is submitted it calls a function that sends a jquery ~ v 1.4 ajax POST to google docs.  (I have tested the google form and it works)

I have encountered the CORS error.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   https://docs.google.com/forms/*****************************************************/formResponse.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

- I obviously cannot move the google doc to the same domain.
- I do not have configuration control of the server.
- I do not want to make any global angularjs changes that would affect
  the many other ajax & $httpProvider uses on the site.
- I do not want to embed the google form as an iframe in the site.

My ajax is

```
$scope.storeEmail = function() {
var email = $scope.fA.email;
$.ajax({type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/***************************/formResponse',
        data: { field_key : email, submit : "Submit"},
        success: function(resp) {
        // give success feedback and redirect page
        }
        error: function(xhr, statusText, error){
          console.log(xhr);
        }        
};
```

**I have tried**
Adding credentials and headers to the ajax request

```
withCredentials: true,
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
}
```

However I cannot (at least I don't think I can) set the 'AccessControlAllow*' parameters.

As a note setting withCredentials does not seem to make a difference on its own.
Setting headers or using other types such as PUT results in a "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed" response.

I tried configuring angularjs with the following

```
App.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
  }
]);
```

However I am new to angularjs and I don't know if this was put into the correct file or if it will have a knock on effect on the other (internal) $httpProvider uses on the site.

I have been told that I need to add an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" header to all HTTP responses from my server.  But as the server is my google documents server I don't think I can do this.

Any help Please.

Answer (score 0):

The two options I'm aware of for cross domain requests are jsonp and CORS. CORS - as you've already noted - requires the hosting server to have CORS headers included in responses. By the sounds of it the Google documents site does not.

Google do have various jsonp options across sheets and document though, so all is not lost - https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample

You could make use of your own server as a middle man, or even use a service such as cors proxy to add the headers you need to the google content you're requesting without having to pay for the bandwidth.

http://www.corsproxy.com/
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing